# How to add some html formated text to every new post in WordPress

Tags: posts, pages

I create posts in which similar text is repeated to me.
Therefore, I would like to make my work easier, and therefore I want every new post to already contain this text.

Example:
Each posts contains the following headings, under which the text that is specific to each post will proceed.

```
<h2> Keywords </h2>

<h2> Similar articles </h2>
```

Where should I insert the predefined text to be included in each new post?
I'm looking for a solution for new posts, not new pages.
But it would be interesting to see a solution for new pages as well.

### My research

I should probably edit the single.php file, but I didn't find where to insert the text.

Comment: Would reusable blocks be what you need? Otherwise, a custom plugin that hooks something or other as the new post page loads?

Answer (score 1):

you can insert it in `single.php`.

find `the_content;` and that is your content, you can insert above or below `the_content;`

Comment: single.php in my theme does not contain "the_content".
I use GeneratePress V 2.4.2.
Just like this
`
  get_template_part( 'content', 'single' );

    // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
    if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ) :
     /**
      * generate_before_comments_container hook.
      *
      * @since 2.1
      */
     do_action( 'generate_before_comments_container' );
     ?>

     <div class="comments-area">
      <?php comments_template(); ?>
     </div>

     <?php
    endif;
`

Comment: so you can insert it above or below `get_template_part( 'content', 'single' );` then

Comment: Can you give an example please?

Comment: I tried to put in there, <h2> foo </h2>  but nothing happened.

Comment: You can also open the `content-single.php` and in there you'll find `the_content()` and can add it that way.  Tiyo's answer is technically correct, you just have to figure out where specifically in your theme you need to do this.